# Como deixar uma coluna do Datagridbview invisivel ao usuario

Tags: c#

Boa tarde.
tenho uma tema em c# que contem um datagridviwer, e estou populando este datagridiview direto com um query do banco de dados, mas tem um coluna que precisa estar no select, mas não posso mostrar ao usuário no datagridiview, como posso deixar esta coluna invisível. A coluna [N° Solic.] tem que ficar invisível para o usuário.

segue o código que populo o datagridview.

```
 private void ListaGrid()
        {
            string strSQL = @"select distinct 
                           pro.Cod_Produto as CODIGO,
                           pro.NomeProduto as PRODUTO,
                           pro.Lote as LOTE,
                           pro.Fabricante AS REPRESENTADA,
                           pro.Qtda as QTDA,
                           sa.Id_Solicitacao AS [N° Solic.]
                      from tbl_SolicitacaoAmostra as sa
                      inner join tbl_Produto as pro with (nolock) on pro.Id_Solicitacao = sa.Id_Solicitacao
                      where sa.Cod_Solictacao = '" + txt_numero.Text + "'";

            comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conex1);

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
                DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
                dados.Fill(dtLista);

                DGW_itens.DataSource = dtLista;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a serem encontrados");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Você definiu as colunas de antemão (pelo designer)?

Comment: Então não defini não, monta direto quando leio a query ele já mostra as colunas de acordo com os nomes que coloquei na query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o que tem até agora, o que pode fazer é mudar a visibilidade da coluna depois de preencher o grid

Algo assim:

```
DGW_itens.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Onde **0** corresponde ao índice que queres esconder.

Ou

```
DGW_itens.Columns["Nome da Coluna"].Visible = false;
```

Onde **Nome da coluna** é o nome produzido no select.

Comment: Perfeito LINQ era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando, muito obrigado.